# Is there a word or phrase for giving something to a highly respected person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a better word choice for **give** when we give something to a highly respected person (or an entity, such as an organization, a government, or a country).

The basic sense of the word **give** is usually sufficient to describe the act of giving something to someone. However, in most Asian cultures, we usually use different words for giving something to a person with equal or lower social status (in this case *give* is quite perfect), from giving something to a person who has higher social status, especially when that person is highly respectable in the society. (A venerable person might be an appropriate term here.) This "something" could be abstract, such as *respect*, *loyalty*, *an honorable title*, or concrete, such as *money*, *a souvenir*, *a celebration*, *a tribute*, and so on.

Some words I found in dictionaries are *offer*, *dedicate*, and *consecrate* are close, but not quite.

Is there a word, or a short phrase, for this verb in English?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word [bestow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bestow) comes to mind.

to convey as a gift —usually used with on or upon

> The university bestowed on her an honorary degree.

Google:

> Confer or present (an honor, right, or gift).
>   "the office was bestowed on him by the chief of state"
>   synonyms:   confer on, grant, accord, afford, endow

Answer (score 4):

[**Present**](http://gog.is/define+present) comes to mind. It's also part of the definition of bestow in [mplungjan's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/142004/51660).

Particularly the definition:

> Give or award formally or ceremonially.
>
> ---
>
> *"They presented him with extravagant gifts"*
>
> ---
>
> You will **present** *something* to them.

I have tried to think of how it could be applied to non physical gifts such as respect, but in those cases I don't think it works well, though I think it could fit if the sentence was structured right.

Something like:

> He was presented with a display of respect and loyalty.

Answer (score 0):

You can "[flatter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flatter?q=flatter)" someone with words, gifts or compliments.